# Use of @ in sql statements or in declaring variables?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, plsql

Is there anyone who told me what is the use of @ in sql statements specially while declaring variables in sql query......thnx for any response.

Answer (score 7):

It's kind of hard to Google for an @ sign isn't it?

Here's a link to [SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188927.aspx) help on this, where it says:

> Variable names must begin with an at
> (@) sign.

And here's a link about declaring variables in [PL-SQL](http://plsql-tutorial.com/plsql-variables.htm), where they are not preceded by the @ sign.

So, **it depends on which particular database you're using.**

Answer (score 2):

It is used to declare variables. For example:

```
Declare @SubID varchar(20)

Declare @MyTable Table 
(
   Column1 int
)
```

Comment: But it can be done in other way like                                                                           declare variable1 varchar(20) then what is its significance???

Comment: No it cannot be done any other way. It has no other significance other than it is used to declare a variable, just like the key word 'Declare' is used to declare a variable.

Comment: @Randy Apparently you are talking about `t-sql`. This question is tagged `pl-sql`. See [DOK's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6636216/use-of-in-sql-statements-or-in-declaring-variables/6636276#6636276).